# INVALID_ARGUMENT Error for Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've got a python pipeline which takes a file from Cloud Storage, removes some columns, then uploads the result to BigQuery. If I run this locally using the Dataflow runner, everything works as expected, but whenever I try to set it up with the Dataflow UI so I can schedule it etc. no job gets created and this
`INVALID_ARGUMENT` error gets thrown in the logs:

*(Ids etc. removed)*

```
{
  "insertId": "...",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "url": "https://datapipelines.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../locations/europe-west1/pipelines/cloudpipeline:run",
    "jobName": "projects/.../locations/europe-west1/jobs/...",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "targetType": "HTTP",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 400
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "location": "europe-west1",
      "project_id": "...",
      "job_id": "..."
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-11-01T10:45:00.657145402Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/.../logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-11-01T10:45:00.657145402Z"
}
```

I can't find out anything about this error and gcp doesn't seem to provide any additional info.

I've tried to use gcp logging in the python code but the gcp error seems to get thrown before any code is executed. I've also removed all of my optional parameters so there shouldn't be anything you're required to enter in the gcp set-up that isn't default.

Comment: Can you share more details on what you are trying to do? You have an existing job, and trying to use the UI to "Import as a pipeline"? Or have you [created a template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) and trying to start it from the UI?

Comment: Can you share the exact command line you executed to launch your job with `Dataflow` runner ?

Comment: @BrunoVolpato Yes I have a template and am trying to create a pipeline using it with the UI

Comment: @MazlumTosun I didn't use the CLI, I just ran the actual python file for the pipeline template with the DataflowRunner chosen in the PipelineOptions